# Number of records in grid AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I tried to count num of rows in grid in runtime with this code

```
FormRun caller;
FormDataSource fds;
QueryRun queryRun;
int64 rows;

fds = caller.dataSource();
query = fds.query();
queryRun = new QueryRun(query);
rows = SysQuery::countTotal(queryRun); //this returns -1587322268
rows = SysQuery::countLoops(queryRun); //this returs 54057
```

The last line of code is closest to what i need because there are 54057 lines but if i add filters it still returns 54057.
I want logic to get the number rows that grid has in the moment of calling the method.

Answer (score 2):

Your query has more than one datasource.

The best way to explain your observation is to look at the implementation of `countTotal` and `countLoops`.

```
public client server static Integer countTotal(QueryRun _queryRun)
{
    container c = SysQuery::countPrim(_queryRun.pack(false));    
    return conpeek(c,1);
}
public client server static Integer countLoops(QueryRun _queryRun)
{
    container c = SysQuery::countPrim(_queryRun.pack(false));    
    return conpeek(c,2);
}
private server static container countPrim(container _queryPack)
{
    ...
    if (countQuery.dataSourceCount() == 1)
        qbds.addSelectionField(fieldnum(Common,RecId),SelectionField::Count);    
    countQueryRun = new QueryRun(countQuery);    
    while (countQueryRun.next())
    {
        common  = countQueryRun.get(countQuery.dataSourceNo(1).table());
        counter += common.RecId;
        loops++;
    }    
    return [counter,loops];
}
```

If your datasource contains one datasource it adds `count(RecId)`.
`countTotal` returns the number of records.
`countLoops` returns 1.
Pretty fast, as fast as the SQL allows.

If your datasource contains more than one datasource it does not add `count(RecId)`.
`countTotal` returns the sum of recIds (makes no sense).
`countLoops` returns the number of records.
Also `countLoops` is slow if there are many records as they are counted one by one.

If you have two datasources and want a fast count, you are on your own:

```
fds = caller.dataSource();
queryRun = new QueryRun(fds.queryRun().query());
queryRun.query().dataSourceNo(2).joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
queryRun.query().dataSourceNo(1).clearFields();
queryRun.query().dataSourceNo(1).addSelectionField(fieldnum(Common,RecId),SelectionField::Count);
queryRun.next();
rows = queryRun.getNo(1).RecId;
```

The reason your count did not respect the filters was because you used `datasource.query()` rather than `datasource.queryRun().query()`. The former is the static query, the latter is the dynamic query with user filters included.

Update, found some old code with a more general approach:

```
static int tableCount(QueryRun _qr)
{
    QueryRun qr;
    Query q = new Query(_qr.query());
    int dsN = _qr.query().dataSourceCount();
    int ds;
    for (ds = 2; ds <= dsN; ++ds)
    {
        if (q.dataSourceNo(ds).joinMode() == JoinMode::OuterJoin)
            q.dataSourceNo(ds).enabled(false);
        else if (q.dataSourceNo(ds).joinMode() == JoinMode::InnerJoin)
        {
            q.dataSourceNo(ds).joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
            q.dataSourceNo(ds).fields().clearFieldList();
        }
    }
    q.dataSourceNo(1).fields().clearFieldList();
    q.dataSourceNo(1).addSelectionField(fieldNum(Common,RecId), SelectionField::Count);
    qr = new QueryRun(q);
    qr.next();
    return any2int(qr.getNo(1).RecId);
}
```